# Installing DateTime.pm using CPAN

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan

I'm installing Perl module DateTime using CPAN.

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell

cpan> install DateTime
```

Following is the directory structure created under DateTime at modules directory

```
total 112
drwxr-xr-x  2 user group 57344 2017-02-02 15:07 Locale
-r--r--r--  1 user group 14449 2017-01-29 13:02 Locale.pm
drwxr-xr-x 13 user group  4096 2017-02-02 15:08 TimeZone
-r--r--r--  1 user group 28040 2016-11-23 23:01 TimeZone.pm
```

I don't find DateTime.pm any where within this directory structure.

Does DateTime.pm comes with any other bundle?

I couldn't find similar question in stackoverflow. Please feel free to point, if the question already exists.

Comment: DateTime.pm isn't inside the DateTime directory; they're both at the same level.

Comment: I don't find it at same level either.

Comment: Please show the output of `ls -l` for the directory above the DateTime directory.

Comment: Nevermind, it's probably because some modules in the DateTime family are pure Perl, and some are XS, so they get installed in different locations. On my system, DateTime.pm is installed in `$PREFIX/lib/site_perl/5.20.2/x86_64-linux/DateTime.pm` (notice the architecture-specific `x86_64-linux` bit), while DateTime::TimeZone is installed in `$PREFIX/lib/site_perl/5.20.2/DateTime/TimeZone.pm`. Use one of the commands ikegami gave in his answer to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be installed in a path of the form

```
$dir_in_INC/DateTime.pm
```

You seem to be looking for a path of the form

```
$dir_in_INC/DateTime/DateTime.pm
```

but that would be for a module named DateTime::DateTime.

---

You can find out where DateTime was installed (assuming it was installed in a location in which Perl searches) using

```
perl -MDateTime -le'print $INC{"DateTime.pm"};'
```

or

```
perldoc -ml DateTime
```

Comment: Didn't find it under @INC dirs. There's a directory named 'x86_64-linux-thread-multi' at same level of 'DateTime' directory. I found DateTime.pm there. But, when I checked file's time stamp, it was installed a month back. Not sure if that was created because of my cpan installation.

Comment: I've just removed DateTime.pm under 'x86_64-linux-thread-multi' directory and installed DateTime again. It is created again under that directory. So, it got installed there. Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: @Kjetil S., `-m` makes `perldoc -l` work for modules without POD. Admittedly, it's not needed here, but I don't see any reason to use `-l` instead of `-ml`.